# What is the pattern to the stomach room with the horns?

Tags: botanicula

I'm not finding a pattern here. When I save/loaded, I found that sometimes none of the first gray horns led to the ostrich parts. (And when I went back to try it again, picking the same horn on the same save game gave randomized results.) Is guess/check via save/load the only way to get through this, or is there a hidden pattern?

[image: ostrich parts]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first, I thought it was random, but it isn't. After much trial and error through clicking at random, I was able to get the chicken (as well as two other cards from this room):

1. Click the bottom horn twice. You *should* get two parts of the same creature.
2. If the parts are for the chicken, click the middle horn.
3. If the parts are for the frog, click the top horn.
4. If the parts are for the snail, click the bottom horn.

If the first two clicks of the horn don't yield the same creature part, don't panic, just start over. It took me about 5 tries using the above method, but I managed to snag the chicken and get out of there.

Comment: Nice work! The bottom horn is the trick.

Comment: Also don't forget to pick up the chicken before you leave ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to do the system with bottom horn, but found [this one](http://forum.amanita-design.net/index.php?topic=3912.0) which worked for me:

```
If on your first blow you get:
Snail head -> lower trumpet -> lower trumpet to create a snail
Frog head -> lower trumpet -> upper trumpet to create a frog
Chicken head -> lower trumpet -> middle trumpet to create a chicken
```