# Where can I find Snek and Zaba in order to unlock their achievements?

Tags: achievements, botanicula

I can't find those two creatures:

- Snek
- Zaba

I want to get their achievements. Where can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the image below as a reference:

> They can be found in Chapter 5, inside the house marked as 4:
>  [image: Houses Map]

For **Snek**:

> blow random hornes while you get a snail head. Than blow the bottom horn while you get the complete creature.

For **Zaba**:

> blow random hornes while you get a frog head. Than blow once the bottom horn and once the top horn.

Source: [jayisgames.com Walkthrough](http://jayisgames.com/archives/2012/04/botanicula.php#walkthrough)

---

For more detailed information on this particular location, see the following question:

> [What is the pattern to the stomach room with the horns?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63308/what-is-the-pattern-to-the-stomach-room-with-the-horns)